# How to replace multiple instances of <br/> tags with something else in string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a variable:

```
var test = "Hello<br/><br/>World";
```

I want to have a function that can replace those with newlines so that the result is:

```
Hello

World
```

I tried using:

```
test = test.replace('<br/>','\r\n');
```

However this just replaces one occurrence of the 
 and not all of them. I want to make sure that it replaces all occurrences of 
 in the text, be it located right next to each other, or if they are in different parts of the same string.

Comment: you can use a gloabl regex instead `test.replace(/\<br\/\>/g,'\r\n');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use string as a pattern in replace function it replaces only first occurrence. You need to use regex pattern with `g` flag

```js
var test = "Hello<br/><br/>World";

test = test.replace(/<br\/>/g,'\r\n');

console.log(test)
```

There's proposal for [`replaceAll`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-replaceall) in which you can use string as pattern and replace all the occurrences

Comment: This for some reason is not working for me, is it because I am using typescript?

Comment: @Rolando it shouldn't make any difference with typescript as well, can you post your typescript or fiddle where you're able to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

> try using this:

```
var test = "Hello<br/><br/>World";
test = test.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '\r\n');
console.log(test)
```